# webBrowser grab only the first Attribute in element (when all classes are the same name)

Tags: c#, html

I made a html grabber for a webbrowser in C#, but I am stuck. 
The webpage looks like this:

```
<tbody class="first class"
  <tc class="second class">
    <td class=" ">abcdefg</td>
    <td class=" ">1233456</td>
    <td class=" ">qwertyo</td>
  </tc>
```

I use this code to get the content of the three classes inside "second class":

```
HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
        theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tbody");
        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
        {                
            curElement.GetElementsByTagName("tc");
            curElement.GetElementsByTagName("td");                

                label1.Text = curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText");
                return;

        }
```

The problem is that this stores ALL 3 contents in label1, so it looks like this:

```
abcdefg123456qwerto
```

Because the classes all have the same name, I can't grab only one content.

Is there a way to only grab the first content inside an element, so that it looks like this?

```
abcdefg
```

Comment: you have tried curElement.GetElementsByTagName("td")[0]? you have to do the foreach loop on the <td> tag..

Comment: When I put this in it gives me a Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment etc. error, and when put in a foreach loop it says identifier expected, but I'm not sure what identifier.

Comment: `curElement.GetElementsByTagName("tc")` you don't use the returned element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested

```
HtmlDocument document = WebBrowser.Document;
if (document != null) {                    
    HtmlElementCollection tableCollection = document.GetElementsByTagName("tbody");
    foreach (HtmlElement table in tableCollection) {
        HtmlElementCollection trColl = table.GetElementsByTagName("tc");
        foreach (HtmlElement row in trColl) {
            tds = row.GetElementsByTagName("td");
            if (tds != null && tds.Count > 1) {

                string neededText = tds[0].InnerText;
                // 1.iteration: neededText == abcdefg
                // 2.iteration: neededText == 123456
                // 3.iteration: neededText == qwertyo

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should work fine, but it says tds does not exist in the current context, and when I declare it as an int it errors. What is tds supposed to be?

Comment: Also it doesn't understand WebBrowser.Document.

Comment: tds is basically an array storing your td objects. WebBrowser.Document should be equivalent to your webBrowser1.Document.

Comment: I took over some code of you, and got it all working. Thanks.